# Regex match only <br/> tags AFTER the 2nd tag

Tags: regex

I guys i need a regex that match only 
 tags AFTER the 2nd tag

Example:

```
<br/>
<br />
------------- Start match
<br />
<br/>
<br />
<br />
<br/>
<br />
<br />
<br/>
------------- End match
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Amber ??????????????????????????

Comment: @christiangobo - I think he meant to link to the answer saying that [you shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454).

Comment: @JosephSilber not sure why you think I'm a 'he', but yes, that answer is the major aspect of that link.

Comment: He comes! Oh my god it is too late.

Comment: That wa a typo. Sorry, my 's' key is misbehaving today...

Comment: @Amber - I definitely didn't mean anything [like this](http://www.cnn.com/2012/05/10/opinion/trapani-brogrammer-culture/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a look behind:

```
(?s)(?<=(.*<br\s*/>.*){2})<br\s*/>
```

#### Edited:

Added the "dot matches newline" switch `(?s)` in case the input has line feeds

Comment: Maybe you need the "multiple line" switch: I have edited the answer - try that.